# Alignment of Child is Smaller Than Alignment of Base

Tags: c++, inheritance, alignment, icc

After much deliberation, I have reduced a problem down to the following simple example:

```
//__declspec(align(16)) class Vec4 {}; //For testing purposes on Windows
//class Vec4 {} __attribute__((__aligned__(16))); //For testing purposes on *nix
class Base { public:
    Vec4 v; //16-byte-aligned struct
};
class Child : public Base {};
static_assert(alignof( Base)>=16,"Check 1");
static_assert(alignof(Child)>=16,"Check 2");
```

Check 1 passes; Check 2 fails.  **My question: Why?**

---

In practice, allocating a `Child` (i.e. `new Child`) will cause `v` to be possibly `8`-byte-aligned (`v` uses SSE, so this in turn causes a crash).

Compiler is Intel Compiler 2016.  I tried g++ and Clang, and they seem okay.  Is this maybe a compiler bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have [asked Intel directly](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/600755).  Although it could initially be reproduced by their team, after a few days, it couldn't be.  Neither I nor they had an explanation.  So, [magic](http://catb.org/jargon/html/M/magic.html) does exist, and no harm done.

As to the actual substance of the question: yes, it appears that the alignment of the child should be at least as large as the alignment of the base, and a compiler that does not do this is in error.

N.B. stack allocations respect the class's `alignof`, but `malloc`/`new` do not (how could they know?).  As the other answer says, custom heap allocators must be used.  This problem is separate from a correct `alignof` per se.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Alignment:

> It is implementation-defined if new-expression, std::allocator::allocate, and std::get_temporary_buffer support over-aligned types. Allocators instantiated with over-aligned types are allowed to fail to instantiate at compile time, to throw std::bad_alloc at runtime, to silently ignore unsupported alignment requirement, or to handle them correctly.

As a workaround I would suggest defining custom `operator new` for your base class.

Comment: While correct, this is irrelevant since there is no allocation happening here.